# Where to store user editable config parameters in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, config

### Question

I'm building a symfony app that does some batch jobs on user's demand. This job is to download all files on a distant server, that weren't on it the last time the user launched this job. To do that, everytime the job is launched, I'd like to store the date of the day. However, for some reasons, this date need to be editable by the user.

The question is : **where is the cleanest place to store this date ?**

### Possible solutions :

- **In the app.yml**

  - Pros:

    - Easy for the user to edit (but need to take care of the spaces & indentation)
    - Usual place for the config
  - Con:

    - Needs the app.ylm to be writtable by PHP, potentialy not a good idea & one more thing to do when deploying.
- **In a table**

  - Pros:

    - Secured, easy to read and write from the app
  - Cons:

    - Hard to reads for a user

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[csSettingsPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/csSettingsPlugin) may do the trick regarding your needs. The settings are exposed to a Doctrine model but cached in prod environment with a configureable TTL.

Answer (score 1):

Since this will change after the site goes live, I would also certainly say put into a database rather editing the .yml files and potentially the whole site down if the yml become corrupted for any reason.

If ease of editing is a concern, you could easily provide a simple web interface for changing the date in the database.

Comment: What table structure would you use ? A table like this : `[id, paramName, paramValue]` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'd go for something like that.  Then in the future you can easily add more config parameters if required.